# How can we pass value to textbox by its name using jquery in Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to pass value in textbox by its name using jquery in asp.net but when i passed the value to textbox the value in textbox is visible for the short time then it disappered every time this is my code

```
    <script type="text/jscript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $('input[name="myb"]').val("mynameabc")
    });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="di1" style="height: 150px">
    <button>ClickME</button>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

    <input id="Text1" name="myb" type="text" />

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a page refresh due to the `asp:Button`.

You need to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function (ev) { //note new parameter here
    $('input[name="myb"]').val("mynameabc")
    ev.preventDefault(); //add this...keeps button from 'submitting' the page
  });
});
```

Alternatively, there is a "UseSubmitBehavior" attribute on `asp:Button` you could use as well...which approach you use may be dependent on what you're trying to accomplish on the page.